# C# PlayerPrefs.Save()

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have two methods to switch between accelerometer and touch controller type. But it doesn't save the preferences. Help?

```
public void InputChoiceFalse()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("playerChoice"))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("playerChoice", playerChoice ? 0:1);
        playerChoice = false;
        Debug.Log("false "+playerChoice);
        value = 0;
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

}

public void InputChoiceTrue()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("playerChoice"))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("playerChoice", playerChoice ? 0 : 1);
        playerChoice = true;
        Debug.Log("true "+playerChoice);
        value = 1;
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint to see if the methods get called?

Comment: I tried with a boolean and works not saved when restarting the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are checking if it exist,  maybe player prefer does not exist so it does not execute at all? 
I also do not know why you have to methods doing almost same thing.  I would recommend to change code.

```
public void InputChoice(bool choice )
{
    playerChoice = choice;
    value = playerChoice ? 0:1;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("playerChoice",value);

    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

Remember DRY(don't repeat yourself) rule. Your code will be much easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for helping .. but I tried with similar code and the result always false .. Its my first game android

Comment: Ok .. I testing with your code its worked but one problem when exit application the game lose the preferences ... thanks for helping

Comment: Got it .. `if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("playerChoice"))
        {

            value =  PlayerPrefs.GetInt("playerChoice", value);

   

        }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to flip the .SetInt after the playerChoice = true, that seemed to work for me.

Comment: I made the switch, but not saved when play and stop

Comment: Thanks for helping

Comment: Works !!! my mistake was worth what I was trying to show the value is saving now.

Comment: ok worked in unity + remote but when I'm generating the apk on mobile does not work .. Any suggestions?

Comment: hmmm, I dont know. You could try getting someone skilled with android games to answer to that.